# Posting JSON to php and then curling to different domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, curl

What i want to achieve: Using HTML/JQUERY and posting `XMLHttpRequest` (JSON) to the php file where we can then submit the json to an external website using `CURL`.

Here is the way i am submitting that data:

```
var myDate = "30/01/2014";
var n=myDate.split("/");
var fdate = (n[2]+"-"+n[1]+"-"+n[0] );

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "index.php");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    alert('Status: '+this.status+'\nHeaders: '+JSON.stringify(this.getAllResponseHeaders())+'\nBody: '+this.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.send("{\n    \"utoken\":  \"\",,\n    \"email\": \"blah@blah.co.uk\",\n    \"customer_name\": \"blah blah\",\n    \"order_id\": \"112897\",\n    \"platform\": \"general\",\n    \"order_date\": \"" + fdate + "\",\n    \"currency_iso\": \"GBP\"\n}");
```

Now how can i get this data within the php and manipulate it. As there are somethings like the `utoken` which i can get from the php file but cannot get the other information.

PHP

```
$chs = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_URL, "EXTERNAL API URL");
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, print_r($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA););
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
$response = curl_exec($chs);
curl_close($chs);
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `json_decode` in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You should format the data you want to send like this:

```
xhr.send("utoken=&email=blah@blah.co.uk&customer_name=blah blah&order_id=112897&platform=general&order_date=" + fdate + "&currency_iso=GBP");
```

The following line won't work either as print_r prints out an array. You also have a syntax error (; inside the function arguments).

```
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, print_r($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA););
```

Instead try:

```
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Since you are posting `JSON`, your post request should be like below:

```
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"utoken":"", "email":"some@xya.xom"}');
```

Or, if you have an array like below, then you can use `json_encode` to make your array into `json` easily for the post.

```
$post_data = array(
    "utoken" => "",
    "email" => "some@xya.com"
);
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_data));
```

FYI: the function `json_encode` converts the array value into `{"utoken":"","email":"some@xya.com"}`